# jQuery stop loop on event

Tags: jquery, function, events

I am just starting with jQuery, so be patient. How do I stop this blinking function on attempted window scroll or mouseenter? Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/e2s8besv/1/

```
<p>blink me<p>

<style>p {display:none;}</style>

<script>
    (function( $ ) {
        $.fn.blink= function(speed) {
        $(this).fadeIn(speed).fadeOut(speed).blink(speed);
    };
}( jQuery));

$("p").blink(1500);
</script>
```

Comment: your fiddle does not show the blink action

Comment: You have an infinite loop here.

Comment: The code in the question is not like in the fiddle. The variable assignments breaks it in fiddle. Another problem is that with your current code, you will reach the maximum call stack rather quickly

Comment: you need to use timeout and set a timer variable

Comment: Edited to direct to correct fiddle. I want the blink function to loop infinitely until an attempted window scroll or mouseenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would most likely do this, if you're learning jQuery and assuming, javascript as well...

**HTML**

```
<p class="hide blink">blink me<p>
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {

  objInt = setInterval(function() {
    $(".blink")
      .fadeTo('fast', 0.2)
      .fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
  }, interval);

  // stop on scroll (only works if there's actualy a scroll area)
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
    clearInterval(objInt);
  });

  // stop on mouseenter the paragraph tag
  $( ".blink" ).mouseenter(function() {
    clearInterval(objInt);
  });

});

var interval = 500, objInt;
```

**live version** in JsBin: http://jsbin.com/gajafokale/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: For others trying to accomplish something similar, I found that the animation speed within the setInterval loop is important, as well as the 'interval' value. The setInterval cannot be interrupted (stopped by clearInterval) while the animation is taking place, so it is beneficial to have fast animations and longer intervals. To set a time between setInterval loop starts, replace the 'interval' with a time (in milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `boolean` flag to check if the action is happening. I would also try to separate the code in functions so that you can reuse them later if needed. Try doing something like this:

HTML:

```
<p style="display:none">BLINK</p>
<button>STOP</button>
```

JS:

```
var blinking = false;

function blink(speed) {
    if (blinking) {
        $("p").fadeIn(speed, function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(speed);
            blink(speed);
        });
    }
}

function startBlink(speed) {
    blinking = true;
    blink(speed);
}

function stopBlink() {
    blinking = false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){//makes sure your code runs once the DOM has completely loaded.
    startBlink(1500);
    $('button').click(stopBlink);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest something with boolean variable and without recursion (would be more CPU-friendly):

```
<p>blink me<p>

<style>p {display:none;}</style>
<button>Stop Blinking!</button>
<script>
    var isBlinkEnabled=true;
    (function( $ ) {
        $.fn.blink= function(speed) {
        while(isBlinkEnabled)
        {
            $(this).fadeIn(speed).fadeOut(speed);
        }
    };
}( jQuery));

$("p").blink(1500);
$("button").click(function(){
  isBlinkingEnabled=false;
})
</script>
```